# File Permission Denied fopen

Tags: php, file-permissions, fopen, permission-denied

I use MS Expressions for creating and publishing sites. I also have a quick page editor built in to my CMS. If I edit the page with my CMS I can no longer edit it with Expressions. I get a file permission error.

Before I save the new info I delete the old page and create a new one. I then give it 0777 permission. Any suggestions?

The page saves fine and shows the correct permission in my Cpanel

```
$ourFileName =(DOCROOT."/template/$myTemplate/$myFile"); 
$page_content = stripslashes("$page_content");

unlink("$ourFileName");

$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($ourFileHandle,"$page_content");
fclose($ourFileHandle);

chmod("$ourFileName", 0755);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that you have correct permissions on directories, too. (757)